# Find even number of entries in several tables

Tags: algorithm, lookup

Given a number `N` and a set of tables constituted of unique elements, how can I find all the sets of N entries that only appear an even number of times in each table?

*Note*: Practically I've got couple of hundred tables, each containing approximately a million of entries where each entry is a number between 0 and 2 millions. And I'm trying to find sets of around 500 numbers.
That's why I'm looking for an efficient algorithm.

For example, given `N=4` and the following tables:

```
Table    #1         #2        #3       #4         #5
        ,---.     ,---.     ,---.     ,---.     ,----.
        | 0 |     | 5 |     | 7 |     | 4 |     |  9 |
        | 1 |     | 3 |     | 6 |     | 1 |     |  7 |
        | 9 |     | 2 |     | 4 |     | 0 |     | 11 |
        | 2 |     | 7 |     | 3 |     | 7 |     | 10 |
        | 8 |     | 6 |     | 9 |     | 5 |     |  2 |
        | 5 |     | 0 |     | 0 |     | 8 |     | 12 |
        '---'     '---'     '---'     '---'     '----'
```

The solutions to find are:

```
Solution      table #1       #2           #3     #4     #5
--------      ------------------------------------------------
0, 2, 4, 10 : [0, 2]       [0, 2]       [0, 4] [0, 4] [2, 10]
0, 1, 2, 9  : [0, 1, 2, 9] [0, 2]       [0, 9] [0, 1] [9, 2]
0, 2, 4, 11 : [0, 2]       [0, 2]       [0, 4] [0, 4] [2, 11]
0, 2, 4, 12 : [0, 2]       [0, 2]       [0, 4] [0, 4] [2, 12]
0, 2, 8, 9  : [0, 8, 2, 9] [0, 2]       [0, 9] [0, 8] [9, 2]
1, 3, 6, 8  : [8, 1]       [3, 6]       [3, 6] [8, 1] []
1, 4, 9, 10 : [1, 9]       []           [9, 4] [1, 4] [9, 10]
1, 4, 9, 11 : [1, 9]       []           [9, 4] [1, 4] [9, 11]
1, 4, 9, 12 : [1, 9]       []           [9, 4] [1, 4] [9, 12]
1, 8, 10, 11: [8, 1]       []           []     [8, 1] [10, 11]
1, 8, 10, 12: [8, 1]       []           []     [8, 1] [10, 12]
1, 8, 11, 12: [8, 1]       []           []     [8, 1] [11, 12]
2, 3, 5, 7  : [2, 5]       [2, 3, 5, 7] [3, 7] [5, 7] [2, 7]
2, 5, 6, 7  : [2, 5]       [2, 5, 6, 7] [6, 7] [5, 7] [2, 7]
3, 6, 10, 11: []           [3, 6]       [3, 6] []     [10, 11]
3, 6, 10, 12: []           [3, 6]       [3, 6] []     [10, 12]
3, 6, 11, 12: []           [3, 6]       [3, 6] []     [11, 12]
4, 8, 9, 10 : [8, 9]       []           [9, 4] [8, 4] [9, 10]
4, 8, 9, 11 : [8, 9]       []           [9, 4] [8, 4] [9, 11]
4, 8, 9, 12 : [8, 9]       []           [9, 4] [8, 4] [9, 12]
```

I've used this python program but it is a naive implementation and I don't like its complexity, which is higher than [image: O(n^N)]:

```
X = (
  (0,1,9,2,8,5),
  (5,3,2,7,6,0),
  (7,6,4,3,9,0),
  (4,1,0,7,5,8),
  (9,7,11,10,2,12)
)
# find unique elements across all lists
ALL = tuple(set([l for i in range(len(X)) for l in X[i]]))
LEN = len(ALL)

def find_all():
  Solutions = []
  for i in range(0, LEN-3):
    for j in range(i+1, LEN-2):
      for k in range(j+1, LEN-1):
        for l in range(k+1, LEN):
          if count_even((ALL[i], ALL[j], ALL[k], ALL[l])):
            Solutions.append([ALL[i], ALL[j], ALL[k], ALL[l]])
  return Solutions

def count_even(values):
  """return True if some elements of `values` appear
     an even number of times in every list"""
  for List in X:
    Accumulator = 0
    for Value in values:
      for Elem in List:
        if Elem == Value:
          Accumulator += 1
    if Accumulator & 1 == 1:
      return False
  return True

for v in find_all():
  print v
```

The function I'm interrested in optimizing is `find_all()` because it has too many nested loops.
Maybe there's something to do using Gaussian elimination or trees, or any other well known algorithm.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: The algorithm you describe is equivalent to: 1) generate a list of all elements that occur an even number of times; 2) generate all combinations of N items from that list.   (1) should take O(n) time. (2) takes time proportional to the output size.

Comment: @MattTimmermans, in second solution '2' and '9' occurs odd number of times

Comment: I've added a python program, a 5th column for the sake of clarity. And also the fact that the lists are constituted of unique elements, it may help.

Comment: Oh, you need each table to contain an even number of items from each set of N...  that makes this an interesting question.  What is the maximum number of tables and highest N?

Comment: I've just answered in the post. hundreds of tables containing millions of entries and I'm trying to make sets of about cardinal around 500.

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry can't comment)

As a small improvement, you can precompute and store (in a hashmap for instance, or in an array if the values are integers from 0 to a known I_MAX) the number of occurences of each element in each table (time O(n*N))

Then:

- build all the sets of N elements O(n^N)
- for each of them,  for each table:
      for each element in the set:
          look up the occurences in the tables, add it to the total for the table. Reject the set if you get an odd result

That takes time O(n*N) + O(n^N) + O(n^N * T * N) which is (for T=N/2): O(N^3 * n^N), which is O(n^N) if N is considered constant compared to n.

Maybe there is a completely different smarter algorithm that does not generate all sets with N elements, but in any case it could happen that you have O(n^N) answers to your problem, so you can't do much better that this in the worst case. (if N is considered constant compared to n).

Answer (score 0):

This one works pretty well if you don't have too many tables.  If you have more than 31 you'd have to change the format of the bit vectors from ints to something more complicated.

The comments explain how it works

```
N=4
TABLES = [
  [0,1,9,2,8,5],
  [5,3,2,7,6,0],
  [7,6,4,3,9,0],
  [4,1,0,7,5,8],
  [9,7,11,10,2,12]
]

#Make a bit mask for each item, with a bit for each table
#The table's bit is 1 if the number occurs an even number
#of times in the table
#A set of N items is then valid iff the masks for those items
#XOR to 0
MASKS={}
bit=1
for table in TABLES:
    for val in table:
        MASKS[val] = MASKS.get(val,0) ^ bit
    bit*=2

ITEMS=sorted(MASKS.keys())

#Make REACHABLE[n][val] = the highest position pos such that
#you can make XOR value val using n elements at positions >= pos
REACHABLE=[]
for n in range(0,N):
    REACHABLE.append({})
REACHABLE[0][0]=len(ITEMS)
for pos in range(len(ITEMS)-1,-1,-1):
    itemval=MASKS[ITEMS[pos]]
    for n in range(N-1,1,-1):
        for testkey in REACHABLE[n-1].keys():
            newval=itemval^testkey
            REACHABLE[n][newval]=REACHABLE[n].get(newval,pos)
    REACHABLE[1][itemval]=REACHABLE[1].get(itemval,pos)

#now print all the solutions using the REACHABLE array to ensure that we
#don't go down any non-viable paths
def printSolutions(prefix, needval, startpos, count):
    if count<1:
        if needval==0:
            print(prefix)
        return
    for pos in range(startpos,len(ITEMS)):
        testval=needval^MASKS[ITEMS[pos]]
        if REACHABLE[count-1].get(testval,-1) > pos:
            prefix.append(ITEMS[pos])
            printSolutions(prefix,testval,pos+1,count-1)
            prefix.pop()

printSolutions([],0,0,N)
```

Making the `REACHABLE` array takes O(N*n*2^(num_tables)) and producing the output takes O(n*number_of_solutions).  Space complexity is O(N*2^(num_tables)).

Obviously, this algorithm can be inefficient if the number of tables is large.  If you have to support a large number of tables then, then you can use something like a Bloom filter (but with XOR) in `REACHABLE` instead of raw bit vectors.  It won't be as good at speeding up the output pass, but but it will `REACHABLE` will be much smaller and quicker to generate.

Here's the output of the above program:

```
[0, 1, 2, 9]
[0, 2, 4, 10]
[0, 2, 4, 11]
[0, 2, 4, 12]
[0, 2, 8, 9]
[1, 3, 6, 8]
[1, 4, 9, 10]
[1, 4, 9, 11]
[1, 4, 9, 12]
[1, 8, 10, 11]
[1, 8, 10, 12]
[1, 8, 11, 12]
[2, 3, 5, 7]
[2, 5, 6, 7]
[3, 6, 10, 11]
[3, 6, 10, 12]
[3, 6, 11, 12]
[4, 8, 9, 10]
[4, 8, 9, 11]
[4, 8, 9, 12]
```

Comment: I like the idea, but unfortunately I've got about 200 tables with each around 1 million entries. The numbers are between 0 and 2 millions. That would make 200 tables x 1 million entries x 2 million bit integers = 50 TB of fast storage and a lot of RAM too. I've added a note to the original post. Thanks!

Comment: Ah,that's too bad. There's a reduction from the maximum independent set problem to this problem that maps each edge to a small table and each vertex to an element.  That means your problem is NP-hard, and all the algorithms you find will be exponential in the number of tables, in the worst case.

Comment: Because of the branch pruning, printSolutions never makes a recursive call that won't print a solution, so it's O(min(n^N, n*number_of_solutions)).  If you have n^(N-1) solutions, then you have other problems.  There certainly are instances of your problem that have n^N solutions, so of course no algorithm will be better than O(n^N) if it has to print them all.